# rubymine emacs shortcut for copying text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I know it is popular to hate on IDEs, but I've been using rubymine in addition to emacs for debugging, etc and it is pretty nice. One thing that is a major pain is that I can't find a keyboard shortcut to copy text when in emacs keyboard shortcut mode. Alt + w is what I am used to. I have been working around this for a couple months by Ctl + w, Ctl + y, but it makes me nervous to cut a large amount of data from my files.

Thanks for any help on this slightly silly, but very annoying problem.

Comment: What OS do you use? Is there any problem with changing the Copy action keyboard shortcut in Settings | Keymap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a guide to the default keys avaliable on the start page of the IDE and you can also remap them in the settings.

See the [default keymap here](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/docs/RubyMine_ReferenceCard.pdf).

Comment: thanks, just need to take a peek in the right place, thanks for the trivial question